# when is start npm I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have installed node js and mongo db then after that I started the node js. when I start the node js I get this error. This error is throwing from server.js file. But I couldn't check exactly which line is throwing error.

```
/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:22404
  href: _react2['default'].PropTypes.string,
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined
at Object.defineProperty.value (/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:22404:38)
at __webpack_require__ (/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:30:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:20101:20)
at __webpack_require__ (/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:30:30)
at Object.i (/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:19923:15)
at __webpack_require__ (/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:30:30)
at Object.defineProperty.value (/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:19790:20)
at __webpack_require__ (/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:30:30)
at Object.defineProperty.value (/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:19000:34)
at __webpack_require__ (/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:30:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:320:22)
at __webpack_require__ (/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:30:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:76:16)
at __webpack_require__ (/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:30:30)
at Object.obj.__esModule.default (/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:57:19)
at __webpack_require__ (/Users/aarthi.ananth/reactjs/reactjs/reaact-csp/CSP/public/build/server.js:30:30)
```

My server.js file has the following code at line 22403

```
var propTypes = {
  href: _react2['default'].PropTypes.string,
  onClick: _react2['default'].PropTypes.func,
  disabled: _react2['default'].PropTypes.bool,
  role: _react2['default'].PropTypes.string,
  tabIndex: _react2['default'].PropTypes.oneOfType([_react2['default'].PropTypes.number, _react2['default'].PropTypes.string]),
  /**
   * this is sort of silly but needed for Button
   */
  componentClass: _elementType2['default']
};
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
 "name": "isomorphicdemo",
 "version": "1.1.1",
 "description": "React Customer care application",
 "main": "src/server/app.js",
 "scripts": {
 "start": "nodemon public/build/server.js"
 },
  "files": [
  "lib/",
  "socket.io.js"
 ],
 "dependencies": {
 "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
 "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
 "babel-plugin-dev-expression": "^0.2.1",
 "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
 "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
 "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
 "babelify": "^8.0.0",
 "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
 "bootbox": "^4.4.0",
 "browserify": "^14.5.0",
 "deep-equal": "^1.0.1",
 "ejs": "^2.3.3",
 "ejs-loader": "^0.3.0",
 "engine.io-client": "^3.1.4",
 "express": "^4.13.3",
 "express-session": "^1.14.1",
 "express-useragent": "^1.0.3",
 "flux": "^3.1.3",
 "gulp-live-server": "0.0.31",
 "history": "^4.7.2",
 "http-proxy": "^1.11.1",
 "invariant": "^2.1.0",
 "jquery": "^3.1.1",
 "json-loader": "^0.5.2",
 "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
 "react": "^16.2.0",
 "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
 "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
 "react-flux": "^1.0.1",
 "react-native-version-check": "^2.0.1",
 "react-router": "^4.2.0",
 "reactify": "^1.1.1",
 "simple-react-button": "^1.3.0",
 "socket.io-client": "^2.0.4",
 "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
 "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
 "superagent": "^3.8.1",
 "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
 "warning": "^3.0.0",
 "webpack": "^3.9.1",
 "websocket": "^1.0.23",
 "ws": "^3.3.2"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
  "browser-sync": "^2.9.6",
  "gulp": "^3.9.0",
  "gulp-babel": "^7.0.0",
  0"nodemon": "^1.7.0"
 }
 }
```

May I know where I am going wrong..

Comment: missing `prop-types` dependency?

Comment: I added but still facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

`"prop-types": "^15.6.0"` dependency is missing in the package.json file. Execute below command in your project to install it.

`npm install --save prop-types`